# How do I attain missing Services on a virtual machine?

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machine, services

knowledgeable persons of the interwebs.

To run SalesLogix on my VM (OS: XP, Service Pack 3,  Version 2002), there are two services that need to be "started" in Services (the screen which launches when we do RUN>'services.msc'). These services are SLXSYSTEM and SQL Instance. Not only are these services not "started" but they are entirely absent ]=<

After some research I determined that I need to install SQL Server Native Client 10 (or 10.5).

Even if I can find this, how would I go about installing it on a VM?

Can I/should I install it from the host?

Is this a VM configuration issue?

Comment: VM is a separate computer. Download installer files onto it or move them there by any method, then install just like you would on any computer. By the way, you'll more likely need SQL Server, not the client.

Comment: woah that was a quick response. Thanks, I will try that. I think I need both according to this source: http://cleverslx.blogspot.com/2011/05/database-login-failed-unable-to.html

Comment: tbh i am such a noob. I have no idea the difference between the SQL Server Client and SQL Server